# Simple character-by-character peer-to-peer chat application

Tags: java, chat

I built this simple application to facilitate communication between two or more machines on a local area network. As each client starts up, it broadcasts and receives broadcast packets; allowing for the omission of inputting a peer's IP address. It then creates a new connection to each discovered peer (even to itself), and characters are updated on-the-fly on each client's interface. I am posting this to get constructive feedback on the coding style, modularization, and its usability.

**LANChat.java**

```
package lanchat;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LANChat extends Frame implements Runnable {
    // text output of all connections
    private final TextArea textArea;
    // broadcast and receive of UDP; used for TCP connection(s) to peer(s)
    private final Broadcasts broadcasts;
    // list of all sockets for TCP output
    private final ArrayList<Socket> sockets;
    // storage for text data
    private StringBuilder lines;
    // continue running application?
    private boolean run = true;

    public LANChat() {
        // create field objects
        sockets = new ArrayList<>();
        lines = new StringBuilder();
        textArea = new TextArea(20, 80);
        // set focusable to false to ensure keys are captured by frame
        textArea.setFocusable(false);
        // monospace ftw
        textArea.setFont(Font.decode("monospaced"));
        // the only gui object is the text area
        add(textArea);
        pack();

        // start socket server to accept incoming connections
        new Thread(this).start();

        // instantiate and assign window listener and key listener to frame
        FrameListener frameListener = new FrameListener(this);
        addWindowListener(frameListener);
        addKeyListener(frameListener);

        // late initialize of UDP broadcast and receive, to ensure needed
        // objects are instantiated
        broadcasts = new Broadcasts(this);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    // global quit method shuts down everything and exits
    public void quit() {
        run = false;
        broadcasts.quit();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // method called by key listener
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
        int i;
        synchronized (sockets) {
            // iterate through all sockets, and flush character through
            for (i = 0; i < sockets.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    Socket s = sockets.get(i);
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
                    pw.print(String.valueOf(ke.getKeyChar()));
                    pw.flush();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // remove socket, continue to any next if exception occurs
                    // (socket closed)
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    sockets.remove(i);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // method called by per-connection thread defined in socketStream
    public void putChar(int ch) {
        // check for backspace and space for delete,
        // otherwise put character into buffer,
        // and show updated buffer
        if (ch == 8 && lines.length() > 0)
            lines.delete(lines.length() - 1, lines.length());
        else
            lines.append((char)ch);
        synchronized (textArea) {
            textArea.setText(lines.toString() + '.');
        }
    }

    // method called by UDP listener
    // exits if connection fails
    void newAddress(InetAddress address) {
        synchronized (sockets) {
            // check if already connected to address, and exit if true
            for (Socket addr: sockets)
                if (addr.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()
                        .equals(address.getHostAddress()))
                    return;
            // create a new socket and add it to transmission pool
            Socket s;
            try {
                s = new Socket(address.getHostAddress(), Globals.TCPPORT);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                return;
            }
            sockets.add(s);
        }
    }

    // called by socket server thread
    // defines a thread for each connection,
    // which calls putChar for every received character
    // exits thread if error occurs (socket closed)
    private void socketStream(final Socket s) {
        final InputStream is;
        try {
            is = s.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return;
        }
        final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (run && s.isConnected()) {
                    try {
                        if (br.ready())
                            putChar(br.read());
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    // socket server accepts incoming connection,
    // and creates a thread to pass characters to the screen
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(Globals.TCPPORT);
            while (ss.isBound() && run) {
                socketStream(ss.accept());
            }
            quit();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            quit();
        }
    }

    // application entry
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LANChat();
    }
}
```

**FrameListener.java**

```
package lanchat;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

public class FrameListener implements WindowListener, KeyListener {
    private final LANChat parent;

    public FrameListener(LANChat parentArg) {
        parent = parentArg;
    }

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent we) {

    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
        parent.quit();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent we) {

    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent we) {

    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent we) {

    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent we) {

    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent we) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
        parent.keyTyped(ke);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {

    }

}
```

**Broadcasts.java**

```
package lanchat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class Broadcasts {

    private final Runnable receiver;
    private final Runnable sender;
    private boolean run = true;

    public Broadcasts(LANChat parent) {
        receiver = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                byte data[] = new byte[0];
                DatagramSocket socket = null;
                try {
                    socket = new DatagramSocket(Globals.UDPPORT);
                } catch (SocketException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    parent.quit();
                }
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
                while (run) {
                    try {
                        socket.receive(packet);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        parent.quit();
                    }
                    parent.newAddress(packet.getAddress());
                }
            }
        };
        sender = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                byte data[] = new byte[0];
                DatagramSocket socket = null;
                try {
                    socket = new DatagramSocket();
                } catch (SocketException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    parent.quit();
                }
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
                        data, 
                        data.length, 
                        Globals.broadcastAddress, 
                        Globals.UDPPORT);
                while (run) {
                    try {
                        socket.send(packet);
                        Thread.sleep(Globals.UDPINTERVAL);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        parent.quit();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        parent.quit();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(receiver).start();
        new Thread(sender).start();
    }

    public void quit() {
        run = false;
    }
}
```

**Globals.java**

```
package lanchat;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InterfaceAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Globals {
    public static final int UDPPORT = 9090;
    public static final int TCPPORT = 9091;
    // delay in milliseconds between broadcasts
    public static final int UDPINTERVAL = 1000;
    public static final InetAddress broadcastAddress;
    static {
        // create broadcast address object refrencing the local machine's
        // broadcasting address for use with UDP
        broadcastAddress = getBroadcastAddress();
        assert (broadcastAddress != null);
    }
    private static InetAddress getBroadcastAddress() {
        ArrayList<NetworkInterface> interfaces = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            interfaces.addAll(Collections.list(
                    NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()));
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        for (NetworkInterface nic: interfaces) {
            try {
                if (!nic.isUp() || nic.isLoopback())
                    continue;
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                continue;
            }
            for (InterfaceAddress ia: nic.getInterfaceAddresses()) {
                if (ia == null || ia.getBroadcast() == null)
                    continue;
                return ia.getBroadcast();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Separation of responsibilities

It would be better if `LANChat` was in charge of less stuff.

> ```
> public class LANChat extends Frame implements Runnable {
> ```

Currently it's a GUI, and it also manages its peers (the sockets).
It would be better to split these responsibilities to multiple classes.

#### Don't `System.exit`

It's not cool to `System.exit`.
It would be better to reorganize the code in a way that when your main logic is finished,
and you cleaned up all resources (close sockets, file handles),
the program would naturally exit.

#### Bug: skipping sockets

There's a bug here:

> ```
>         for (i = 0; i < sockets.size(); i++) {
>             try {
>                 Socket s = sockets.get(i);
>                 PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
>                 pw.print(String.valueOf(ke.getKeyChar()));
>                 pw.flush();
>             } catch (IOException ex) {
>                 // remove socket, continue to any next if exception occurs
>                 // (socket closed)
>                 ex.printStackTrace();
>                 sockets.remove(i);
>                 continue;
>             }
>         }
> ```

When you iterate over the indexes, for example 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
and at `i=3` you remove a socket (`sockets.remove(3)`),
but the loop counter still advances to `i=4`.
The original item-4 is now item-3 since the original item-3 was removed.
In other words, the socket after a removed socket will be skipped.

Here's one way to fix that:

```
        List<Socket> toRemove = new LinkedList<>();

        for (Socket s : sockets) {
            try {
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
                pw.print(String.valueOf(ke.getKeyChar()));
                pw.flush();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                toRemove.add(s);
            }
        }

        sockets.removeAll(toRemove);
```

#### Avoid magic numbers

> ```
>     // check for backspace and space for delete, [...]
>     if (ch == 8 && lines.length() > 0)
> ```

Although the comment (sort of) explains that 8 is the backspace character,
it would be better to use the more idiomatic `'\b'` instead.
If `'\b'` is not obviously backspace to some readers,
you could even define a `BACKSPACE` constant for it.